# Tern auto-complete won't start automatically

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, tern

When I enter "pars" in Emacs js-mode buffer and type `tern-ac-complete`, I get the desired result: list of completion candidates + the documentation next to the candidate.

However, I cannot get Tern completion to be triggered automatically. The `ac-auto-start` is set to `3` and the auto-complete works as expected for other cases (my dictionary file, the words I already typed in, jquery-doc, etc.)

Comment: Can you post your `tern` configuration please?

Comment: If you are thinking about my .emacs file, here it is:
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook (lambda () (tern-mode t)))
(eval-after-load 'tern
   '(progn
      (require 'tern-auto-complete)
      (tern-ac-setup)))

Answer (score 1):

You should try [company-mode](http://company-mode.github.io/) with the third-party [company-tern](https://github.com/proofit404/company-tern/).

It starts completion automatically with no problems.

Comment: +1. Here's my Emacs Prelude snippet: ```(global-company-mode +1)
(eval-after-load 'company
  '(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-tern))```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `tern` does not provide an `ac-source` yet. From the comments in `tern-auto-complete.el`

> This program does not provide an ac-source for arbitrary timing yet.

Comment: I was wandering whether this line means what you say it means :) Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. You want to bind this command to `tab` or some key.

Answer (score 0):

Call function 'edebug-defun for function 'ac-start of auto-complete.el,
and follow call trace to figure out what causes this problem.

In my case, **variable 'ac-use-dictionary-as-stop-words was t** and having many words on my auto completion dictionary, 
so auto-complete was aborted.

```
tern.el          : Version: 0.0.1
auto-complete.el : Version: 1.4.0
```

line. 1559            (ac-abort)) ;; <= This was called!!!

```
$ node --version # v0.11.13-pre (on Linux)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because tern-emacs has to request completions from tern-server (an async operation). Only when the server returns it goes on to call auto-complete with the tern sources only.

I fixed it by advising auto-complete to wait for tern request if a custom variable is set to t. This way you can get tern completions to show in your normal auto-complete workflow.

Here is the [pull request](https://github.com/marijnh/tern/pull/546) (or just the [diff](https://github.com/marijnh/tern/pull/546/files?diff=unified)) I made to the tern repo.

I'm adding this here in case someone stumbles here through search as i did.